# Why doesn't gedit show up in wmctrl, xlib, or similar tools?

Tags: python, ubuntu, x11

I'm writing a simple python module that can return the x,y coordinates and titles of all open windows as a part of a larger program.  I thought I'd test it with gedit.  But it doesn't seem to matter which technology I use, gedit doesn't show up in the list of open windows.  Nautilus doesn't either.  That includes python tools like EWMH or python-xlib, or Ubuntu command line tools like wmctrl.

To recreate, open up a few apps and run `wmctrl -l` in the terminal.  Now open up a nautilus window and a gedit window.  Run `wmctrl -l` again.

Why doesn't nautilus or gedit show up?  Is there a way to query all open windows and get information on them?

Comment: Since this happens when you use `wmctrl`, it has nothing to do with Python programming. It's a question about the window manager you're using, and [unix.se] or [ubuntu.se] would be better places to ask.

Comment: Do you have a Wayland desktop by any chance?

Comment: Wayland?  Interesting.  It looks like I am. echo $WAYLAND_DISPLAY returns wayland-0

Comment: wmctrl doesn't know about Wayland windows.